# If $G_X$ is a Probability Generating Function of $X$, what does it mean by $G_X(0)=\mathbb P(X=0)$ and $G_X(1)=1$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, probability-generating-fn

Let $G_X$ is a Probability Generating Function of $X$.

What does it mean by

- $G_X(0)=\mathbb P(X=0)$ ?
- $G_X(1)=1$ ?

**Why are these identities important?**

Answer (score 1):

The [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) (PGF) of a discrete non-negative random variable $X$ is defined to be $G_X(t) = E(t^X)$.

For your first question, suppose $G_X(0) = E(0^X)$. If we take $0^0=1$ then $$E(0^x) = \sum \limits_{x=0}^\infty 0^x f(x) = f(0) = P(X=0)$$ where $f$ is the pmf of $X$.

The second one is easier: $G_X(1) = E(1^X) = E(1) = 1$

As for why these are important, we can recover the pmf of $X$ via derivatives of $G_X$. In the wikipedia article that I linked to they state that 
$$
P(X = k) = \frac{G_X^{(k)}(0)}{k!}
$$
so if we want to know $P(X=k)$ for all $k$ then we need to know $G_X^{(k)}(0)$ for each $k \in \mathbb N$, and so $G_X(0) = G_X^{(0)}(0) / 0!$ gets that started. Thus the fact that $P(X=0) = G_X(0)$ is the first step in how we can get the pmf $f$ out of $G_X$.

The result that $E(1^X) = 1$ means that $\sum_x 1^x f(x) = \sum_x f(x) = 1$ so this is equivalent to $f$ being normalized to sum to 1 which is a necessary property for any pmf.